# Updating .EPS file automatically in LaTeX (Overleaf)

Tags: overleaf

Is there a way to update an .EPS file automatically within Overleaf?
Some context: I have an organic chemistry reaction mechanism drawn in Chemdraw and saved as an .EPS file uploaded on Overleaf. Let's say there are some features that I want to change; I apply the changes and save the file. The .EPS on my computer updates, naturally, but the one on Overleaf doesn't. How can I somehow link the two without uploading the file again with the submitted changes? Maybe API keys could be of use? But I have little to no experience with those.

Comment: Ask Overleaf support. However, mintime you should upload changes to Oveleaf too (I'm affray, that there is not other options).-

Comment: If you have a paid account, you could synchronise the file via github, dropbox etc.

Comment: I've already stated "le simple approach" in my own words: "without uploading the file again with the submitted changes". I'm interested in something more 21st century-esque.

Comment: see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Dropbox_Synchronization and https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_Git_and_GitHub for details

Comment: Thanks! If I have an institutional account, do I benefit from those features free of charge?

Comment: @TheRelentlessNucleophile The linked article explains which groups can use this.